# Use pmdarima library from Python in Scala code and Spark - time series

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, time-series, arima

I would like to apply Auto Regressive (AR) model in a scala code using a Spark Session to make some predictions on a time series.
Eventually, I will also use Moving Average (MA) model.

Is ARIMA a good solution for that?

Is there a trusted library in Scala that deploys these models?

I also found *pmdarima* library in Python, is there a way to use it using my Scala code and Spark environment?

What are other alternatives?

Comment: I found this lib, but it seems outdated: https://github.com/twosigma/flint#:~:text=Flint%20is%20Two%20Sigma's%20implementation,to%20provide%20locality%2Dbased%20optimizations. As far as I know, Spark has not other lib for time-series.